# Clone/Duplicate product image gallery

Tags: product, image, product-attribute, media, gallery

I'd like to "clone" the image gallery from product A to a product B.
And with "clone" I mean with all mediaattributes and basically all what is related to the images in the gallery (position, image url, "is thumbnail", "is baseimage", etc.).

Now I now that the product gallery is stored EAV. I've already found the "media_gallery" attribute within the eav_attributes table. Also catalog_product_entity_media_gallery and catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value seem to be involved.

Neither the Product Media Api nor the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media offer methods to get my task done.
Has anyone got a brainwave?